# Need help understanding what "(2..Math.sqrt(n)).none?" means in a method that sums the primes below a number

Tags: ruby, algorithm

```
def prime_sum_below(x)
    primes = (2..x).select { |n| (2..Math.sqrt(n)).none? { |i| (n % i).zero? }}
    sum = primes.inject { |sum, i| sum + i }
end
```

The method sums the primes below x. I have trouble understanding "(2..Math.sqrt(n)).none?". What exactly does it do?

From the ruby guide, .none? passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method returns true if the block never returns true for all elements. If the block is not given, none? will return true only if none of the collection members is true.

I don't fully understand that, could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me rephrase it like this:

```
primes = (2..x).select do |n|
  (2..Math.sqrt(n)).none? do |i|
     (n % i).zero?
  end
end
```

And then go through each line:

```
# It selects a number if the following block returns true
primes = (2..x).select do |n|

  # It takes all of the elements from 2 to the square root of n
  (2..Math.sqrt(n))

  # Then passes that into another block, returning true if none of the elements return true
  .none? do |i|

     # If it never divides evenly, then it returns true
     (n % i).zero?
  end
end
```

So if `(n % i).zero?` returns true, it means that something goes into `n`, meaning `n` cannot be a prime number